# Export excel file using repeater (all data)

Tags: c#, excel

I want to export all bind repeater data in single excel file.

Using this code only first page of repeater is exporting but I want the whole repeater data.

This is my C# code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Detail.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
rptrdata.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write("<table>");
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.Write("</table>");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the records that binds in the repeater has all the page values or that current page values.

Comment: I have one problem I download excel file but it is not coming proper format means excel cell does not apply border means separation please give some solution.

Comment: What if the repeater is inside an update panel? It's not working for me. Thanks